# Change create date of a folder with PHP

Tags: php, windows, touch, directory

I could not make it work. I can change the modification time of a file, but with folder nothing happen and function alway return true.

Platform: Windows 10 64bit, PHP 5.5.12

Code:

```
$sync_from = "c:\\abc";
$sync_to = "d:\\abc";
//In c:\abc have a folder name: folder_a
$link = "d:\\abc\\folder_a";
//Create folder_a in d:\abc
mkdir($link);
//get time of source folder (c:\abc\folder_a)
$time = filemtime(str_replace($sync_to, $sync_from, $link));
//change time of just create folder
if (!touch($link, $time)) echo "Could not change modification time\r\n";
```

Comment: any errors? see if error reporting throws back anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: No error, folder just not change the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking for changing the modification date, or asking for the creation date. For modification date of a folder, the following code is working perfectly. Check if you're making some mistake of the `time` not being set in one of the variables!

```
<?php

$link = "SomeFolder";

//Set 2 hours back
$time = time() - 7200;

if (touch($link, $time)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: ahh, very sorry, my bad, after change folder time, I create some new file in it, so time change again immediately.

Comment: @NotthingCtrl, that is a consequence of NTFS, not PHP. If you did it on a FAT partition (like a flash-drive, memory-card, RAM drive, etc.), then it will not be updated.